# Files and Directories Included in CRAN Submission

Tags: r, package, cran, r-devtools

I would like to submit a package to CRAN using `devtools::release` and omit a few files and directories from the submission. When uploading a package to Github, files and directories can be excluded by listing them in `.gitignore`. What I am looking for is the CRAN counterpart of that. Judging from the explanations on [this](https://r-pkgs.org/release.html) site, listing files in `.Rbuildignore` only excludes them from the package bundle, but not from the CRAN submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still right about `.Rbuildignore`. If you use `devtools::build()`, it will only build files not in `.Rbuildignore`. So that built file is ready to submit to CRAN.

I even think `devtools::submit_cran()` builds as well, but I'm not sure about that.

After submission, you can check the status of the submission here: https://cran.r-project.org/incoming/. If it's your first submission, the package will be in https://cran.r-project.org/incoming/newbies/.

Better yet, check your submission on this dashboard: https://lockedata.github.io/cransays/articles/dashboard.html.